# Swift Package Manager and Cocoapods together: Compiler errors in Swift Package after Cocoapod Pod addition

Tags: parse-platform, cocoapods, parse-server, swift-package-manager, jitsi-meet

I am developing an iOS app using the ParseSwift SDK. When I set up my project I added ParseSwift via the Swift Package Manager, which worked like a charm. Server connection and saving and querying for data on the server all works and my app compiles in its current state.

To add online meeting capabilities I have been trying to add the JitsiMeet iOS SDK.

After trying to add it via Swift Package Manager, I read on the Jitsi forum that the preferred way of adding it to an existing project is via Cocoapods, and there are currently no plans of supporting the Swift Package Manager. After finding several questions about interoperability of SPM and Cocoapods here I was hoping it would be smooth sailing.

After some back and forth to make Cocoapods work with my M1, I then tried several different Podfile variants to successfully add the JitsiMeetSDK Pod to my project. These variants include:

- adding or leaving out the `platform` part so it is assigned by Cocoapods
- adding or leaving out `use_frameworks!`
- installing with or without the `post_install` block (which is taken from the Jitsi documentation)

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'JitsiMeetSDK'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

The short version is: this does not work. My app doesn't compile anymore.

Here is the strange part: while Cocoapods successfully adds the JitsiMeetSDK Pod, when I open the .xcworkspace file and try to compile it I now get tons of compiler warnings for the ParseSwift package that I added via the Swift Package Manager. These errors all concern Concurrency or features only available in iOS 15 - which should not be a problem, since I set the platform to `ios, '15.0'` in my Podfile.

The ParseSwift files are also annotated and do have checks for Concurrency, which is why I understand this error even less. (screenshots of compiler errors and annotations below)

Is there an order that I have to follow when it comes to adding packages (first Cocoapods, then SPM)? Or any App settings I need to change now that two package managers are in the mix? Any help is appreciated!

I am using

- Xcode 13.1
- Swift version 5.5.1 (arm64)
- Cocoapods 1.11.2 (installed via Home-brew for M1 support)
- ParseSwift SDK 2.5.0 (via SPM)
- JitsiMeet SDK 4.0.0 (via Cocoapods)

Here is a screenshot of the error messages (one example of almost 300 such cases):
[image: Compiler errors after adding JitsiMeetSDK Pod to project with SPM-added ParseSwift package.]

Answer (score 0):

So, I used your Podfile with a new project and ended up with the exact same result.

Then I tried first run Cocoapods for JitsiMeetSDK, then adding the ParseSwift with SPM. Same result.

The only way I was able to make it work was by having Cocoapods install both ParseSwift and JitsiMeetSDK.

```
platform :ios, '15.0'

target 'TestPackageManagers (iOS)' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'JitsiMeetSDK'
  pod 'ParseSwift'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

pod install ran like a charm and I was able to compile and run everything.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but not all library dependencies support all dependency managers. For instance, I was recently forced to switch to SPM for an old library called 'Then' because the older versions of the library don't compile on the latest version of Xcode, but they have discontinued Cocoapods support for the new version of the library completely. However, I have other libraries in the same project that only support Cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Ash for your comments! I just tried using your Podfile @Alex Kusmenkovsky without `pod 'ParseSwift'` on my existing project (ParseSwift added via SPM) after updating to Xcode 13.2.1 and now I can at least build my project from the workspace file, with JitsiMeetSDK successfully added.

Comment: The Concurrency errors went away after updating to Xcode 13.2, however I ended up with new errors about missing package descriptions - something that happened to many other people as well and was a bug in Xcode 13.2: [Apple Developer Forum: Xcode 13.2 - Internal error : Missing Package Description Module](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504?page=2)

Comment: Updating to Xcode 13.2.1 fixed the Missing Package Description Module error, and apparently it also fixed my described problem with using two different package managers for ParseSwift and JitsiMeetSDK.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using `ParseSwift SDK 2.5.0` in Xcode `13.1`. This isn't possible.

Xcode made changes related to backwards compatibility in Xcode 13.2+.

You can resolve everything easily by upgrading to Xcode 13.2+. If you look at the [release notes](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/releases/tag/2.4.0) for ParseSwift it says specifically:

> Requires Xcode 13.2 or above to use async/await. Not compatible with Xcode 13.0/1, will need to upgrade to 13.2+. Still works with Xcode 11/12

Basically, ParseSwift 2.4.0+ requires Xcode 13.2+. If you want to use Xcode 13.1 or lower, you need to use ParseSwift 2.3.1 or lower. More info can be found in the [PR](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/pull/278#issue-1048052768) that made the change.

You will face this same issue with any dependency that adds the async/await backwards compatibility for iOS13, so it's recommended to upgrade to Xcode 13.2+ sooner than later.

In addition, the problem isn't related to a mix of SPM and Cocoapods, these dependency managers have nothing to do with each other and you shouldn't have any issues using ParseSwift through SPM along with others in Cocoapods.

Comment: Hey Corey, thank you, that was the issue regarding the ParseSwift Concurrency errors! I realised I had recently updated my package dependencies prior to adding the JitsiMeetSDK via Cocoapods, and Xcode did not update automatically (had to go into the App Store and start the update manually). After the update, the mentioned errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

The described Concurrency errors were due to updating the ParseSwift package dependencies without updating Xcode to 13.2+ as @CoreyB pointed out.

Xcode 13.2 introduced other, unrelated bugs to my project but solved the Concurrency issue. The bugs were an Xcode 13.2 issue, and updating to Xcode 13.2.1 fixed these bugs.

After the update, I was able to add JitsiMeetSDK via Cocoapods to my existing project.

Thanks to @CoreyB and @Alex Kusmenkovsky for their helpful input!